# Combining two streams of numbers using linq or rx

Tags: linq, system.reactive

I was playing around with linq/rx and wanted to do something simple, create a stream that listens to two different streams of numbers and when either number stream gets a new value, output the sums.

I tried the below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numSrcA = new Subject<int>();
    var numSrcB = new Subject<int>();

    var resultsLinq = from a in numSrcA
                      from b in numSrcB
                      select a + b;

    var resultsRx = numSrcA.SelectMany(a => numSrcB, (a, b) => a + b);

    resultsLinq.Subscribe(r => Console.WriteLine("Linq: " + r));
    resultsRx.Subscribe(r => Console.WriteLine("Rx: " + r));

    numSrcA.OnNext(1);
    numSrcB.OnNext(2);
    numSrcA.OnNext(3);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Linq: 3
Rx: 3
```

I was expecting:

```
Linq: 3
Rx: 3
Linq: 5
Rx: 5
```

Though it seems that the new sum will only be computed when numSrcB gets a new value (in which case it sums that new value against all existing values in numSrcA).

Can this be changed so that an addition to either numSrc will recompute the sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you want a combinator that doesn't require new input on all streams to trigger the evaluation of the result - in other words, you want `CombineLatest`:

```
var resultsLinq2 = Observable.CombineLatest(numSrcA, numSrcB, (a,b) => a+b);    
resultsLinq2.Subscribe(r => Console.WriteLine("Linq2: " + r));
```

Results in:

```
Linq2: 3
Linq: 3
Rx: 3
Linq2: 5
```